# Using redux-observable to perform XHR then dispatch success/failure

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

Moving a large codebase built on redux-thunk over to redux-observable and am struggling to figure out the semantics of an epic that will:

1. Listen for the LOAD action
2. Perform an XHR
3. Dispatch an appropriate SUCCESS or FAILURE action

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
export function editEpic(action$, unusedStore, { xhrClient }) {
  return action$
    .ofType(LOAD_ACTION)
    .map(({ apiParams, operationId }) => {
      // xhrClient is an object with methods on it that
      // return a Promise of the data
      const editOperation = xhrClient[operationId];

      // call the api now
      return editOperation(apiParams);
    })
    .map(result => {
      return { type: SUCCESS_ACTION, result };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // We never get here..
      return { type: FAILURE_ACTION, error };
    });
}
```

This works just fine when the API call is successful, however in the event that the Promise rejects with an error, the `catch` operation never gets called.

Could someone point me in the right direction here? We are using:

- `redux-observable@0.18.0`
- `rxjs@5.5.11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that that first .map should instead be a .switchMap, .concatMap, or .mergeMap instead. To verify this, stick a log statement in the success case to see what `result` equals, and i expect you'll see that it's a promise, not the value that the promise resolves to. Furthermore, the promise will be in a pending state; not yet resolved/rejected.

The choice of switch vs concat vs merge will depend on what you want to do if multiple LOAD_ACTION are kicked off in quick succession before the first one can complete. Switch will cancel the first in favor of the new one; concat will wait for the first to complete before moving on to the second; merge will do them in whatever order it can, with no guarantee of the order of the results.